# <textarea> output is not well encoded

Tags: wordpress, encoding

This is my first question, so sorry if I make any mistake in my explanations.

I created a website based on Wordpress that uses a Newsletter plugin.
I'm not using that plugin, I'm using it only to generate an HTML newsletter.

Here is how it goes : I got to a specific page in my back-office and there is dropdown selection where I can pick up articles from specific categories in my blog.

Once I selected what I want, I have my "Generate" button that :

- Generate HTML code based on a php template I created
- Show me a preview

To prevent any encoding error, I used the str_replace function with a lot of characters.
That works very well for my preview, but not for the generated code (that appears in a textarea).

So I was wondering how to fix this, because in the textarea I have "�" and some "Â" appearing in my content.
For your information, this is the only problem I have, on the website everything shows well, it's just on that Newsletter Generator that I have an issue !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Make sure you've gone [**UTF-8 all the way through**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), including saving the file **as** UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help and answers,

I finally solved it that way :

In the PHP file that output the generated HTML code (in the textarea), the outpu was generated that way :

```
htmlentities($newsletter);
```

And I replaced it by this :

```
htmlentities($newsletter, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
```

And now it seems to work like a charm !! I will come back if there is any more issue, but that way works for me and the generated HTML code is now well and don't show any weird character !

Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the following in your header template? Within head, before the `<title` tag.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Comment: I did, in the output HTML code in the textarea I have this, but I don't think it's the problem.
Because this part is also output in the textarea, and have no incidence on the generated code.